# Sort array alphabetically in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting, advanced-custom-fields

I'm creating a website for a book publishing company. They've books in multiple different languages and want to display some details for each language. To retrieve all the necessary information for each language, I do the following:

```
  <div class="col-lg-3" align="center">
        <?php
            $fields = get_field_objects();                  
                if ($fields):
                    foreach ($fields as $name => $field):    
                        if (stripos($name, 'isbn') !== false) : ?>
                            <?php $lang = substr($field['name'], strpos($field['name'], "_")); ?>
                            <div class="panel-group">
                                <div class="panel panel-default">
                                    <div class="panel-heading">
                                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                                            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1<?php echo $lang ?>">Deutsch/<?php echo substr($field['label'], strpos($field['label'], " ") + 1); ?></a>
                                        </h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="collapse1<?php echo $lang ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                      // ... get all neccessary information ...
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif;
                    endforeach;
                endif; ?>
            </div>
```

Now my problem is, that if somebody creates a book, forgets to add a language and wants to add it after the book has been saved to the database, the alphabetical order is not correct anymore. 
Therefore I'd like to add a sorting function for the $fields array.

sort($fields) doesn't work since after doing this, everything is blank.

Here's a screenshot of how the output looks like. 
[image]

And sometimes, the order is wrong (e.g. Deutsch/English appears on the bottom). So I'll have to sort the part where I add the second language (next to German). The part where I add this is here:

```
 <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1<?php echo $lang ?>">Deutsch/<?php echo substr($field['label'], strpos($field['label'], " ") + 1); ?></a>
 </h4>
```

Does anyone have any ideas? Please let me know if code is missing!

P.S. the plugin I use is "Advanced-Custom-Fields" and the functions like e.g. "get_field_objects()" come with that plugin!

Comment: `asort();` not working?

Comment: @LeoTahk no, weirdly enough, when using asort() my output is 
English, French, Spanish, Italian, Arabic, Persian, Greek, Turkish.
Without asort() it's
French, Greek, Italian, Persian, Spanish, Turkish, English, Arabic.

Comment: Ooooh! I just tried "ksort()" instead and it worked! Man that feels stupid. You can add your comment as an answer if you want to.. Thanks!!

Comment: @LeoTahk sorry, forgot to mention you in my comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what solve my problem is @LeoTahk 's suggestion of adding ksort().

Final code:

```
    <div class="col-lg-3" align="center">
      <?php
         $fields = get_field_objects();
//working solution
         ksort($fields);

         if($fields):
           ....
         endif; ?>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_field_objects()` returns an array of custom field objects. You can sort it alphabetically using `uasort` like this:

```
$fields = get_field_objects();
uasort($fields,"sort_alphabetically");
function sort_alphabetically($a,$b) {
    return $a['name'] > $b['name'];
}
```

Comment: hmm when adding this, I get the following error: 
Warning: uasort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'sort_alphabetically' not found or invalid function name in ...

Comment: Where did you add the `sort_alphabetically` function? You will need to put it inside your theme's functions.php, then you can call it from `uasort` from other template file.

Comment: Or just write as an anonymous function call: `uasort($fields, function($a, $b) {return $a['name'] <=> $b['name'];});`